# something about COUNT('')

Tags: php

I found a question in `php7.3.4`.

```
if ( count( '' ) == 1 )
{
    echo 1;
}  else {
    echo 2;
}
```

This program output 1.Then I checked the  source for the function 'count'.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(count)
{
    ....
    switch (Z_TYPE_P(array)) {
        case IS_NULL:
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable");
            RETURN_LONG(0);
        break;
        case IS_ARRAY:
            ...
        break;
        case IS_OBJECT:
            ....
        break;
        default:
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Parameter must be an array or an object 
            that implements Countable");
            RETURN_LONG(1);
        break;
}
```

This is easy to producing BUG.
I think it `count('')`  maybe output error or 0  is better than 1 and a Warning.
What do you think about?
And `count(NULL)` is not equal to `count('')`,It feels strange.

Comment: `null` !== `''` - they're different data types. They're not synonyms

Comment: I understand what you're saying,BUT MY question is---count('') maybe output error or 0 is better than 1 and a Warning.

Comment: That is not a question. That is a suggestion, which if you are really concerned about, should be addressed to the community developing PHP [here](https://php.net/support.php), not to Stack Overflow. (I assume the rationale behind `1` is - "one of whatever you passed" - i.e. "one string".) Strings already have several other ways to tell you their length, you don't need to use `count`.

Comment: Thanks for you help.I'm going to take this proposal to the community:D

Comment: In `PHP` the count mainly used to calculate `array` count/length. If you want find the string length use `strlen()` insteed of `count()`. Please refer this link.(https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strlen).

Comment: And added one point, the `count()` is should return '1' if the string is available even empty also. Because it is a array count calculator. If you use count(null) it return `0`. This place the null refer 'nothing'. But the empty string is consider as a string with `0` length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`count()` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php):

> Returns the number of elements in `array_or_countable`. When the parameter is neither an array nor an object with implemented `Countable` interface, `1` will be returned.

`count('')` thus returns `1`, just like `count('seventeen')` returns `1`. Working as intended.